# BizTalk - A4SWIFT - Parsing error after deployment

Tags: biztalk, swift-mt

After redeploying an orchestration to my server, I get the following error:

> Publishing failed message to MessageBox. Details: The single message of type -1, whose 
>       Interchange ID is {89A731D7-6CBF-45EF-9462-2B810C6DA124}, has been marked as 
>       A4SWIFT_Failed=True in the MessageBox database by the SWIFT Disassembler.
>       This message failed with 2 parse errors, 0 XML validation errors, and 0 BRE validation 
>       errors.
>
> ```
> Error details can be extracted from the failed message in the MessageBox database by 
> subscribing to messages where A4SWIFT_Failed=True
> ```

The orchestration used to work and I know that the message I am doing the test with is valid.

Maybe I forgot something while deploying, but I doubt it.

Did anybody have this kind of error before?

Answer (score 0):

My friends Brendan recently solved this problem.

This is a problem with the file version of the assembly file Microsoft.Solutions.FinancialServices.SWIFT.RuntimeSchemas.dll.

Make sure that file have same version in:

1. your project solution
2. under "c:\windows\assembly" (use gacutil to force install it)
3. in resources under your deploy project in Biztalk server
   administrator console

Redeploy the project, and restart the Biztalk server instance!

The correct file version that works for me is 3.9.469.0, and it is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Accelerator for SWIFT\Assemblies."